# Определение индекса выбранного option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребята вот одинаковый код для двух селектов на моей сайте.
Я определяю индекс выбранного OPTION. Проблема в том, что при изменении первого селекта значение индекса всегда определяется верно. А при изменении второго - всегда в "-1". Почему ?

```
var index1 = $('[value='+have+']');
var index1_cookie = $('#select-currencies__have option').index(index1);
console.log(index1_cookie);
Cookies.set('shuf1', index1_cookie);

var index2 = $('[value='+want+']');
var index2_cookie = $('#select-currencies__want option').index(index2);
console.log(index2_cookie);
Cookies.set('shuf2', index2_cookie);
```

Comment: Этот код показывает лишь выборку дом элементов, их логирование и установку в куки. Больше ничего.

Comment: @Александр Щербаков Покажите, пожалуйста, чуть больше кода, чтобы можно было точно сказать.

Comment: Больше ничего не происходит, у меня есть тупо 2 одинаковых селекта с набором опшенов.

Comment: @АлександрЩербаков Чтобы можно было ответить на Ваш вопрос, необходимо видеть, как Вы отслеживаете изменение поля `select` и что за параметры `have` и `want`, которые Вы используете для поиска.

Comment: Действие самое простое - изменение элемента селекта

Answer (score 0):

Вот так выглядит один из селектов:

```
<select id="select-currencies__have" name="have" tabindex="-1">
    <option></option>
    <option value="bch">Bitcoin Cash</option>
    <option value="btc">Bitcoin</option>
    <option value="eth">Ethereum</option>
    <option value="eur">Евро</option>
    <option value="gbp">Фунт стерлингов</option>
    <option value="ltc">Litecoin</option>
    <option value="pzm">Prizm</option>
    <option value="rub">Рубль</option>
    <option value="usd">Доллар</option>
    <option value="wvs">Waves</option>
    <option value="xrp">Ripple</option>
</select>
```

Вот так второй:

```
<select id="select-currencies__want" name="want" tabindex="-1">
    <option></option>
    <option value="bch">Bitcoin Cash</option>
    <option value="btc">Bitcoin</option>
    <option value="eth">Ethereum</option>
    <option value="eur">Евро</option>
    <option value="gbp">Фунт стерлингов</option>
    <option value="ltc">Litecoin</option>
    <option value="pzm">Prizm</option>
    <option value="rub">Рубль</option>
    <option value="usd">Доллар</option>
    <option value="wvs">Waves</option>
    <option value="xrp">Ripple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему же "index1_cookie" всегда разный и верный, а "index2_cookie" всегда в "-1"

Answer (score 0):

В index2 у вас попадает option из первого select'а. Естественно, он отсутствует во втором select'е.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var elem1 = document.getElementById('select-currencies__have');
    var elem2 = document.getElementById('select-currencies__want');
    elem1.onchange = function () {
        var index1 = elem1.selectedIndex; // Получаем индекс селекта
        var text1 = elem1.value; // Получаем значение селекта Это если его тоже захотите использовать
        //document.cookie = 'shuf1= ' + index1; // Сохраняем в куки
        console.log(index1); // Выводим индекс
        //console.log(document.cookie); // Выводим все куки.

    };
    elem2.onchange = function () {
        var index2 = elem2.selectedIndex; // Получаем индекс селекта
        var text2 = elem2.value; // Получаем значение селекта Это если его тоже захотите использовать
        //document.cookie = 'shuf2= ' + index2; // Сохраняем в куки
        console.log(index2); // Выводим индекс
        //console.log(document.cookie); // Выводим все куки.
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-currencies__have" name="have" tabindex="-1">
    <option></option>
    <option value="bch">Bitcoin Cash</option>
    <option value="btc">Bitcoin</option>
    <option value="eth">Ethereum</option>
    <option value="eur">Евро</option>
    <option value="gbp">Фунт стерлингов</option>
    <option value="ltc">Litecoin</option>
    <option value="pzm">Prizm</option>
    <option value="rub">Рубль</option>
    <option value="usd">Доллар</option>
    <option value="wvs">Waves</option>
    <option value="xrp">Ripple</option>
</select>
<select id="select-currencies__want" name="want" tabindex="-1">
    <option></option>
    <option value="bch">Bitcoin Cash</option>
    <option value="btc">Bitcoin</option>
    <option value="eth">Ethereum</option>
    <option value="eur">Евро</option>
    <option value="gbp">Фунт стерлингов</option>
    <option value="ltc">Litecoin</option>
    <option value="pzm">Prizm</option>
    <option value="rub">Рубль</option>
    <option value="usd">Доллар</option>
    <option value="wvs">Waves</option>
    <option value="xrp">Ripple</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала не стоит искать value сразу по всему DOM, ибо у вас в обоих селектах находятся одни и те же значения. Ищите только там где нужно.

**Ищем индекс опций по значению**

```
var index1_cookie = $(`#select-currencies__have option[value=${have}]`).index();
var index2_cookie = $('#select-currencies__want option[value=${want}]').index();
```

**Ищем индекс выбранных опции**

```
var index1_cookie = $(`#select-currencies__have option:selected`).index();
var index2_cookie = $('#select-currencies__want option:selected').index();
```